# If the multiplication of two matrices equals a diagonal matrix, what can be said about them?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

let's suppose we have three square matrices $A$, $B$ and $D$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix.
If $A*B = D$, what can be said about $A$ and $B$? is there any known forms that these two matrices satisfy?

Comment: The entries from the matrices come from which field?

Comment: Work backwards. You want $AB=D$, this happens when $B=A^{-1}D$. SO it does not matter what $A$ is as far as it is invertible. B$B$ can be chosen suitably to make the product diagonal.

Comment: The entries are real.

Comment: @PVanchinathan In fact for any $A$, we can find $B$ such that $AB$ is a diagonal matrix with $0$-$1$-entries (actually, $B=0$ makes $AB$ diagonall as well)

Comment: If the diagonal matrix $D$ is invertible, then $A,B$ are invertible and @PVanchinathan 's comment shows how $A$ and $B$ must be related.  If $D$ is allowed to be singular, then either $A$ or $B$ must be singular and there are many possibilities.

Comment: @PVanchinathan: Since Ziad seems happy with the material shared in Comments, would you like to summarize and present that as an Answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my comment earlier repackaged as an answer:
As the aim is to get $AB=D$ with $D$ diagonal, one can work backwards, and see that $B= A^{-1}D$. This puts a mild condition that $A$ be non-singular and $B$ defined this way. As non-singular matrices $A$ can be otherwise very  general (upper or lower triangular, or orthogonal, or symmetric etc). Other commenters have shown even singular $A$ is possible.